Packaged ue4 sample project aimet at 64-bit does not work, 32-bit does
Using ue 4.21, i have tried packaging one of the template projects(rolling) for 64-win, and i can't launch the resulting .exe. The program shortly shows up in the task manager, but nothing pops up on screen, and it closes in task manager again.
If i package the same project for 32-win, everything works as expected, and i can "play the game".
If i try to do the same thing in ue5.3, both versions works.
The pc is new, i have installed visual c++ redistributables, and directX runetime.
Nvidia drives have been installed both manually and through geforce experince.
Do you have any ideas what the issue could be?
System info:
Windows 10, tried updating to 11, 64-bit
Unreal Engine Editor v4.21
cpu: I9
ram: 64gb ddr5
Grapichs: RTX 4090

